# Print a single page multiple times, counting up the page number

Tags: page-numbering, templates

I (still :) have a ham-radio logbook, a single a4 page which I fill out manually (so this is just an empty form/a template of sorts). Please see below for the code.

The page number is on the bottom left. I'd like to automatically print this one page multiple times, counting up the page numbers (whenever I need more pages to fill out - ham radio *is* fun sometimes!).

So basically I'd like to tell TeX "Take this template and print it 10 times, numbering the pages from 13 to 22".

Any ideas would be highly appreciated, as always.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.6cm, right=0.5cm,top=3.7cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,type1cm,eso-pic}
\makeatletter
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{
            \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}
            \setlength{\@tempdimc}{0.85\paperheight}
            \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
            \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){
            \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{0}{\textcolor[gray]{.4}
            {\fontsize{2cm}{2cm}\selectfont{Amateurfunk-Log DC1TS}}}}}
    }

    \AddToShipoutPicture*{
            \setlength{\@tempdimb}{0.02\paperwidth}
            \setlength{\@tempdimc}{0.12\paperheight}
            \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
            \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){
            \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{270}{\textcolor[gray]{0.65}
            {\fontsize{1cm}{1cm}\selectfont{Seite 004}}}}}
    }

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{8ex}}c}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
    \rowcolors{3}{gray!5}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{
    | M{2cm} %Datum
    | M{1.3cm}  %Zeit Start
    | M{1.3cm}  %Zeit Ende
    | M{2cm}  %Frequenz
    | M{1.5cm}  %Mode
    | M{3cm}  %Rufzeichen
    | M{3cm}  %Name
    | M{3cm}  %QTH
    | M{1.3cm} %Power
    | M{0.9cm} %Report gegeben
    | M{0.9cm} %Report erhalten
    | M{0.8cm} %QSL gesendet
    | M{0.8cm} %QSL erhalten
    |}
    \hline
    Datum & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Zeit UTC} &
    Frequenz & Mode & Rufzeichen & Name & QTH & Power &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Report} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{QSL}  \\ [1ex]

    & Start & Ende & (MHz) &  &  & & & (W) & geg. & empf. & ges. & erh. \\ [1ex]
    \hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]    \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Error:
[image: Picture of error occuring]

Comment: If I add more pages to your document, I don't get any subsequent page numbers. Was this intended?

Comment: yes, but inly out of lack of knowing; this basically is a one-page template, all other pages would be exactly the same. until now I only altered the line containing the hard-coded line number and printed it, repeating these steps multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use TikZ for this application. It not only gives you access to the `\foreach` functionality, but also allows for flexible positioning of text on the page. Also, using the `\pgfmathprintnumber` command you can automatically typeset the page numbers in the format you used (with leading zeros).

Note that you need to run LaTeX twice to get the placement of the page numbers and the title:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.6cm, right=0.5cm,top=3.7cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,type1cm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{8ex}}c}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\rowcolors{3}{gray!5}{white}

\foreach \n in {10,...,20} {
\pgfmathsetmacro\pageno{\n/1000}
\tikz [remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.north) [
        yshift=-2cm,
        black!60!white,
        scale=4.5] {Amateurfunk-Log DC1TS}
    node at (current page.south west) [
        black!60!white,
        rotate=-90,
        anchor=south east,
        scale=2.2,
        inner xsep=1em] {Seite $\mathsf{
            \pgfmathprintnumber[
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=3,
                skip 0.,
                dec sep={}
            ]{\pageno}}$};  

    \begin{tabular}{
    | M{2cm} %Datum
    | M{1.3cm}  %Zeit Start
    | M{1.3cm}  %Zeit Ende
    | M{2cm}  %Frequenz
    | M{1.5cm}  %Mode
    | M{3cm}  %Rufzeichen
    | M{3cm}  %Name
    | M{3cm}  %QTH
    | M{1.3cm} %Power
    | M{0.9cm} %Report gegeben
    | M{0.9cm} %Report erhalten
    | M{0.8cm} %QSL gesendet
    | M{0.8cm} %QSL erhalten
    |}
    \hline
    Datum & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Zeit UTC} &
    Frequenz & Mode & Rufzeichen & Name & QTH & Power &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Report} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{QSL}  \\ [1ex]

    & Start & Ende & (MHz) &  &  & & & (W) & geg. & empf. & ges. & erh. \\ [1ex]
    \hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]    \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \newpage
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever `\pgfmathprintnumber` hack there to get the leading zeroes! I considered using it but concluded it couldn't do what was needed here - didn't even think of something like this.

Comment: I get a repeating error, as shown here: http://pastebin.com/at8TGEQR (can't post it here, somehow...). Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using an older version of `pgf` - try upgrading to 2.10 (which is installed in TeX Live 2011 if you feel like upgrading the whole thing, or just get the package from ctan).

Comment: Yes, this is because you're using PGF 2.0. You should definitely update that package to 2.1.

Comment: All is well that ends well. Upgrading my Mac OS X TeXLive to 2011 solved it. Thank you!

Comment: Aaaaactually - there is an error occuring that I just noticed, coming up usually starting on the seventh page. Please see picture of error in my original question above. Building the PDF does not yield any errors, though.

Comment: @Christian: It looks like you didn't compile twice. The placement of TikZ objects with `overlay, remember picture` is only correct on the second compiler run

Comment: Ahh... Poor n00b needs to be told that! ;) - I.e. Thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to use `pgffor`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.6cm, right=0.5cm,top=3.7cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,type1cm,eso-pic,pgffor}
\makeatletter
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{
            \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}
            \setlength{\@tempdimc}{0.85\paperheight}
            \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
            \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){
            \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{0}{\textcolor[gray]{.4}
            {\fontsize{2cm}{2cm}\selectfont{Amateurfunk-Log DC1TS}}}}}
    }

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{8ex}}c}

\begin{document}
\foreach\pagenumber in {13, ..., 22} {

    \AddToShipoutPicture*{
            \setlength{\@tempdimb}{0.02\paperwidth}
            \setlength{\@tempdimc}{0.12\paperheight}
            \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
            \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){
            \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{270}{\textcolor[gray]{0.65}
            {\fontsize{1cm}{1cm}\selectfont{Seite 0\pagenumber}}}}}
    }

\sffamily
    \rowcolors{3}{gray!5}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{
    | M{2cm} %Datum
    | M{1.3cm}  %Zeit Start
    | M{1.3cm}  %Zeit Ende
    | M{2cm}  %Frequenz
    | M{1.5cm}  %Mode
    | M{3cm}  %Rufzeichen
    | M{3cm}  %Name
    | M{3cm}  %QTH
    | M{1.3cm} %Power
    | M{0.9cm} %Report gegeben
    | M{0.9cm} %Report erhalten
    | M{0.8cm} %QSL gesendet
    | M{0.8cm} %QSL erhalten
    |}
    \hline
    Datum & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Zeit UTC} &
    Frequenz & Mode & Rufzeichen & Name & QTH & Power &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Report} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{QSL}  \\ [1ex]

    & Start & Ende & (MHz) &  &  & & & (W) & geg. & empf. & ges. & erh. \\ [1ex]
    \hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]    \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \hline
    & : & : & & & & & & & & & & \\ [4ex]        \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|C|}{\textcolor{black!10}{\Huge\bfseries Notizen}}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\newpage
}
\end{document}
```

At the moment this is hardcoded for two-digit page numbers, but with a little bit more work you could add the right number of zeros depending on the page number, if you need that functionality.